# Why is middleware not executed when there are multiple calls to app.UseEndpoints(..)?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

I have a situation where a middleware is skipped because of multiple calls to `app.UseEndpoints(...)`.

Looking at this startup code, I would expect `SetUser()` middleware to be executed before MVC controller.
[image: HTTP request pipeline configuration]

But when debugging this, the breakpoint is never hit.

Is it allowed to configure endpoints at multiple places in the application's HTTP request pipeline? If yes, why is the middleware not executed?

To reproduce the problem, create a new ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVC web application. Replace Startup.cs with the code below. Then, set a breakpoint to the middleware, run the app and confirm that the middleware is not executed.

```
using System;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

namespace Carter50Repro
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddHealthChecks();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapHealthChecks("/health");
            });

            app.Use(SetUser);
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }

        private Task SetUser(HttpContext context, Func<Task> next)
        {
            context.User = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(new Claim[]
                {
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "userId")
                }, JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme));
            return next.Invoke();
        }
    }
}
```

I have also posted this question as an issue in ASP.NET Core's GitHub page https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/17750

Comment: *Don't* add multiple calls to `UseEndpoints`. Each call overrides the previous one *at best*. There's no reason to do so anyway. What are you trying to do? Create an anonymous healthcheck endpoint ?

Comment: Yea, put both `endpoint.MapXxx` calls in one `UseEndpoints` and put that **after** your middleware (middlewares are executed in the order they are registered and endpoints is registered first

Comment: P.S. you should never have to tamper around claims principal and User context yourself. Looks cheesy, use proper way to authorize. Not sure what your code is supposed to do, fake a signed in user??! Your auth setup just seems plain wrong

Comment: +1 to Tseng's comments: authentication is the job of the authentication middleware. It's already possible to specify different authentication options for different endpoints, *through* the authentication middleware, eg using the correct attributes.

Comment: Manipulating HttpContext.User manually is done only to demonstrate the issue as easily as possible. Please ignore that implementation detail and focus on the actual issue, middleware being skipped.

Comment: I can think of a few valid reasons to making multiple calls to `UseEndpoints()` in different points of the HTTP request pipeline. For example, consider a computationally (or IO-wise) expensive middleware that is only needed for certain requests. One could short circuit the HTTP request pipeline when the expensive middleware is not needed.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Your comment "Each call overrides the previous one at best" is not accurate. Each call adds the endpoints as expected, it is only that they are not necessarily executed where you'd expect them to execute, which is what this issue is about. I'm trying to figure out if this is indeed against recommendations, as I can see some valid use cases for applying `UseEndpoints` in different places in the HTTP request pipeline.

Comment: @jussi.mattila but your code has a problem, and few (if any) examples, questions or Github projects call `UseEndpoints` twice. In any case, it's impossible to reproduce the issue because you posted images, not code

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Umm, there are clear instructions in the issue how to repro this: "To reproduce the problem, create a new ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVC web application. Replace Startup.cs with this: https://gist.github.com/jussimattila/047ab4936f943ed8b0f2a6574c2525a5. Then, set a breakpoint to the middleware, run the app and confirm that the middleware is not executed."

Comment: Post *the code* in the *question itself*. People aren't going to visit links that may already be stale or missing. If you delete that code this question becomes meanigless

Comment: `Each call adds the endpoints as expected,` if that's the case, all endpoints are configured *before* your own middleware. When a request executes, it will go through the endpoints middleware with all its configured routes first

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Indeed, that appears to be the case. I still think it is unexpected and unwanted. This can become an issue as 3rd party libraries start using endpoint routing. Before this change, I could easily add middleware anywhere in the HTTP request pipeline and it would work as expected. Now if I add a middleware and it internally uses endpoint routing, any middleware after that will be ignored. Can you see this could be a problem?

Comment: It won't be an issue because no library has an expectation it will be the *first* library to configure that particular middleware, or that they should do so at all. That's a top-level application concern. They can provide helpers to make configuration easier. They know they can only configure *their* middlewre and only at specific plages, ie the `AddXYZ` and `UseXYZ` methods

Comment: If a library wants to add its own endpoints, the normal way is to create its own `MapXYZ` method. That already works with ASP.NET Core, allowing the same project to include Razor, Web API, Blazor, and libraries like `Exceptional`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Ok, I'll accept that and hope that all library authors do the right thing. What about my example of a computationally expensive middleware or middleware that calls a slow external service. With endpoint routing, I'm unable to map cheap routes before that middleware and expensive routes after the middleware. The only option is branching the pipeline then. I think it would be nice if mapping of additional routes later worked _as expected_.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You seem to misunderstand how endpoint routing works. There are two middlewares that endpoint routing runs: The *routing* middleware, invoked by `app.UseRouting()`, and the *endpoint* middleware, invoked by `app.UseEndpoints(…)`.

The routing middleware runs first and its job is to essentially figure out what endpoint is being requested. It uses the information from the request to figure that out. When it’s done, it saves that information to be used for later. It does not actually produce any output.

After the routing middleware, you will want to run other middlewares that can make use of the endpoint information. For example the authorization middleware can then make its checks to figure out whether the user is authorized to access the requested endpoint.

Finally, the endpoint middleware runs. When it does, it will *only* run the endpoint that was determined to run by the routing middleware. All the other endpoints that you have configured in the `UseEndpoints(…)` call are ignored.

The endpoint middleware is usually expected to be the last middleware that runs because usually you want it to actually respond to the request, with whatever system was requested (MVC, SignalR, whatever).

So yes, you *can* use `UseEndpoints(…)` multiple times but it will likely not do what you expect it to do. All configuration delegates passed to `UseEndpoints` are combined to specify what `UseRouting()` will actually do. So multiple calls to `UseEndpoints` will all just configure that single routing middleware. And then, when the first endpoint middleware is executed, it will execute whatever endpoint was requested—regardless of whether that endpoint was configured in that exact `UseEndpoints` call.

This means that multiple calls to `UseEndpoints(…)` are almost always a sign that you are doing something wrong. In your case, by splitting up the endpoint configuration, you won’t actually be able to split up the work that some middleware needs to do. So your `SetUser` will actually never run for either endpoint because it is after some endpoint middleware.

If you want to actually avoid calling `SetUser` for some routes, then you should actually make use of the information that endpoint routing provides you with and have your middleware conditionally run. You can get the [determined `Endpoint`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.endpoint?view=aspnetcore-3.0) using `httpContext.GetEndpoint()` and then browse its metadata to decide whether you need to do something.

---

That all being said, if your goal is to authenticate a user with a given identity, then you’re better off using e.g. cookie authentication and then sign in the principal directly. That way you are building on top of the authentication stack.

Comment: Thanks a lot! After asking the question, I have been reading a lot and my understanding of what goes on internally has improved. What you wrote further helps and I feel that I'm now (finally) grasping how endpoint routing really works. Also, we are doing authentication properly. Setting HttpContext.User was done just to demonstrate the issue. While testing this, I had a view that showed the user in a view, so that's why it was like this in the repro. :)

Comment: While I now have much better understand of endpoint routing, I think this was an easy mistake to make. `app.UseRouting()` is configured by call(s) to `app.UseEndpoints()` elsewhere in the pipeline, which is slightly unintuitive. And adding endpoints at a particular position in the pipeline doesn't necessarily add them there, it just modifies the routing configuration. ASP.NET Core could warn that this isn't recommended or supported, or throw an exception if multiple calls to `app.UseEndpoints()` are made.

Comment: Re-reading this, I noticed that there is one mistake in your answer. You wrote that `SetUser` runs always. Actually, it never runs, the breakpoint is _never_ hit. The first call to `app.UseEndpoints` is where the routing is executed and controller methods are invoked in the pipeline. This terminates the request before it ever gets to the `SetUser` middleware.

Comment: @jussi.mattila Yes, you’re right, thanks! I explained it correctly but ignored the correct conclusion about `SetUser`. And about `UseEndpoints` actually configuring `UseRouting`: Yes, that feels unintuitive but if you compare it with the alternative, where you configure the endpoints with `UseRouting` instead (much earlier in the pipeline), then that isn’t really intuitive either. But yeah, it’s certainly a thing you will need to understand if you are writing custom middleware.