# Does a call to MapRazorPages() constitute a call to UseEndpoints()?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-routing, razor-pages

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.endpointroutingapplicationbuilderextensions.userouting?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.EndpointRoutingApplicationBuilderExtensions.UseRouting)%3Bk(DevLang-VB)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=aspnetcore-7.0#remarks) for `UseRouting()`, we must call `UseEndpoints()` afterward:

> A call to UseRouting(IApplicationBuilder) must be followed by a call to UseEndpoints(IApplicationBuilder, Action) for the same IApplicationBuilder instance.

But in some code samples (e.g. [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#configure-signalr)) I see `UseRouting()` calls with `UseEndpoints()` omitted and `MapRazorPages()` used instead. Is this safe?

I entered this query into [ChatGPT](https://chat.openai.com/chat):

> What is the difference between App.MapRazorPages and App.UseEndpoints(Sub(Routes) Routes.MapRazorPages)?

...and it returned this helpful answer:

> `App.MapRazorPages` is a method that configures the routing for Razor pages in an ASP.NET Core application. It adds a default route for all Razor pages, which is `{page}/{handler?}`, where `page` is the name of the Razor page and `handler` is the name of an optional handler method defined within the page.

> `App.UseEndpoints` is a method that enables you to specify a pipeline of middleware that will be executed when a request is received by the application. Within the lambda expression provided to UseEndpoints, you can call `MapRazorPages` to add a route for Razor pages to the pipeline.

> So, in short, `App.MapRazorPages` is a specific method that configures routing for razor pages, while `App.UseEndpoints` is a more general method that allows you to specify a pipeline of middleware and register various types of endpoints, including razor pages, in the application.

All well and good. Very nice. But what about the admonition from the documentation, that we must call `UseEndpoints()` at some point after we call `UseRouting()`? Is it safe to rely on only a call to `MapRazorPages()` to fulfill that requirement?

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59293836) seems to indicate so, but I'd like to make sure before I go stringing things together that I don't fully understand.

**---EDIT---**

Well, go figure.

I consulted the almighty ChatGPT on this one (should've done that at first, I guess) and he boomed down:

> No, it is not safe to rely on a call to `MapRazorPages()` as a substitute for the required call to `UseEndpoints()`.

> `UseRouting()` is used to enable routing in an ASP.NET Core application. It sets up the routing system and prepares the app to handle incoming requests.

> `MapRazorPages()` is an extension method that can be used to configure Razor pages in an ASP.NET Core application. It adds a Razor pages endpoint to the application's endpoint routing table, which allows the app to handle requests for Razor pages.

> `UseEndpoints()` is used to define the endpoints for an ASP.NET Core application. It adds a route to the application's endpoint routing table for each endpoint defined within the lambda passed to it.

> So, while `MapRazorPages()` can be used to configure razor pages and add a corresponding endpoint to the application's endpoint routing table, it cannot be used as a substitute for `UseEndpoints()`. `UseEndpoints()` is required to properly define the endpoints for an ASP.NET Core application and handle incoming requests.

So there we have it. But should we trust it? I'm a little bit wary, perhaps because I tend to prefer to live on the edge and not allow myself to be lulled into complacency by The Matrix.

Can someone corroborate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It differs in different .NET versions.

For example, in .NET 5, you have to call `app.UseEndpoints()` to register routing. However, in .NET 6 you can register routes with a call to `app.MapRazorPage()` directly, leaving out both `app.UseRouting()` and `app.UseEndpoints()`. This is documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-6.0#routing-basics).

> Apps typically don't need to call `UseRouting` or `UseEndpoints`. WebApplicationBuilder configures a middleware pipeline that wraps middleware added in Program.cs with `UseRouting` and `UseEndpoints`. However, apps can change the order in which `UseRouting` and `UseEndpoints` run by calling these methods explicitly.

Comment: Very good, thank you.